# how to get app to just display the current time instead of a countdown?

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/PButcher/flipdown

i'm not sure whether i'd need to manage the rotors as well, or if there's just an easy way to make it count upwards from now() & reset at 24:00

Comment: Looking at the docs on Github, it certainly does seem as though it is built to countdown and not do much else.  You may do better by searching for a library that natively supports the behavior you seek, as I imagine if you _are_ able to get flipdown to behave to your requirements it will not be pretty.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

lazy solution; this essentially works if you just check the current time button. https://www.dwuser.com/education/content/easy-javascript-jquery-countdown-clock-builder/